# App giving "cant open .app because classic environment is not supported" on other macs but works fine on my own

Tags: macos, bash, osascript, platypus

I have written an app that is a bash script, the whole thing is a bash script, and it calls a few osascripts, also for user input mostly, it works awesome on my computer, and so I used platypus to turn the script into an app so that I could send it to a friend, well when he tries to open it, it says you can't open the application ** because the classic environment is no longer supported: http://www.imgur.com/ze0ya4B.png

Any Mac running bash should be able to at least run through right? Could it be something with osascripts? I can't find anything in forums where someone has the same problem and solves it.

Tl;Dr: bash script put through platypus, and new .app file gives error when another Mac tries to open it.

I am running mountain lion so my macbook should not support the classic environment either, what could be making other computers think that there is something from a classic environment. If you think it would help I can upload my source code.

Answer (score 9):

I have to assume that the error I was getting was not very relative to any of the information I gave. It turns out you can't just email a .app file and expect it to come out in tact on the other side. I zipped the app in a folder and it works fine. Incase anyone comes across this same problem, I thought I'd post my situation... I hope this helps someone at some point because I was sure bashing my head against a desk.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure the message is misleading, and it's actually not runnable for some other reason. That dialog box looks like an older version of OS X; might it be too old to run the version of Platypus you're using? The [current version](http://sveinbjorn.org/platypus) requires OS X v10.5 or later running on an Intel CPU. For OS X 10.4 and/or PowerPC CPUs, Sveinbjorn Thordarson (the author) recommends Platypus version 4.4 from [here](http://sveinbjorn.org/files/software/platypus/).

Comment: I tried all of your advice and then it turned out that it was just gmail that didn't say anything about the attachment not working. So basically I zipped the file in a folder and it worked fine, I assume this is because application files on mac are directories? Who knows, thanks for the suggestions anyway!